# temparature gauge does not read until driving car longer than 10 minutes

Tags: radiator

I had my Toyota 2002 radiator hoses change, with that, the radiator had to be flush and filled with new antifreezer. Now the care temperature does not show until driving the car over 10 minutes. I am wondering if the temperature is been read right and if there is any fix. the temp mark does not go beyond half. please help

Comment: The temp shouldn't go beyond half. It's fine.

Comment: Was the thermostat changed as well?

Answer (score 2):

This does not sound like a problem to me. If you had your hoses changed and a flush then your cooling system probably was not working properly, the coolant was likely not circulating well. If that was the case then your car would heat up very quickly and the temperature gauge would get very high. Now that your radiator has been flushed your cooling system is working better, the coolant is circulating freely and is able to use your entire radiator for cooling, so it will take longer for the coolant to heat up. It will also mean that your temperature will stay lower, which is a good thing.